# Explain Principal Wood's reaction after looking at Spike in the mirror

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer

In the Buffy Season 7 episode *First Date*, Principle Wood is driving Buffy (passenger seat) and Spike (rear seat) in his car. He asks Buffy how she knows Spike and looks at him in his rear-view mirror. At this point he doesn't know that Spike is a vampire (he finds out 10 minutes later).

- If he **did** see Spike, how? since vampires can't be seen in mirrors

  > even vampires with souls, such as Angel
- If he **didn't** see Spike, why didn't he react?

Comment: I struggled to answer this the [last time it was asked](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83693/did-spike-get-his-reflection-back-with-his-soul). My only guess is that it was a huge goof that no-one spotted.

Comment: In Buffy, [vampires do appear in reflections occasionally](http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_super/10/101085/1877852-him_xander_and_spike.jpg). Just not silvered mirrors, which kinda makes sense.

Comment: @Richard Darn! The dupe didn't show up before I ask this question.

Comment: @Richard Also their clothes don't reflect either...